# Selenium unable to locate element - Frame

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a python script using selenium to fill the searching box on the site: http://acervo.bndigital.bn.br/sophia/index.html. My code:

```
chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://acervo.bndigital.bn.br/sophia/index.html')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#div_rap > table > tbody > tr > td > form > input.input_busca').send_keys('test')
```

I've already tried to use `find_element_by_css_selector` and `find_element_by_xpath` but it didn't work. I got the error message:

`NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#div_rap > table > tbody > tr > td > form > input.input_busca"}`

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Edit your Q to include the smallest amount of code that python readers can copy/paste into their local environment and duplicate your problem.  AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic), [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) and [mcve] before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry! I tried to correct my post. Thank you.

Comment: Good Show! Nothing to be sorry about! Glad you got the help you need. With a code sample, I can up-vote your Q. Good luck and keep posting (with code samples, required input and output and current output and error messages! ;-) ).(I didn't downvote before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing issue due to iframe. you need to switch to iframe before you start entering your text to inputbox.

Please refer below solution :

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://acervo.bndigital.bn.br/sophia/index.html")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('frame').send_keys("Keys.ESCAPE")
driver.switch_to.frame("mainFrame")
inputBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='rapida_campo']")))
inputBox.send_keys("your test")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I'm new on the forum, so I can't upvote your answer, but I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
input_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/input[1]")
input_element.send_keys("Enter your value")
input_element.submit()
```